# laravel get user information from another table problem

Tags: php, laravel, admin

I use this code to get all bank accounts of my users in admin page and keep in mind that i already define `uid` to relate to user id in my table.

my problem is i can't find a way to show that each bank account related to what account and user info.
what is wrong?

Here is my controller :

```
public function cards()
{
    $cards=DB::table('cards')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
    return view('admin.cards' , compact('cards'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have to join your users table with card table.Then you will get your desired solution.you can try this.

$id = Your user id;

```
public function cards()
    {
        $cards=DB::table('cards')
               ->join('users','users.id','=','cards.uid')
               ->select('cards.*')
               ->where('users.id'=$id);
               ->get();
    }
```

Comment: here's cards table : https://pasteboard.co/IujeNEl.png
here's users table : https://pasteboard.co/IujfkLW.png

Comment: i have status in both tables , when i get {{$card->status}} in my view it returns users table status , how i can get cards table status?

Comment: You get card table status.if you want user table status us write ->select('cards.*','users.*')

Answer (score 1):

Use `->joins()` or  `->leftJoins()`,  `->rightJoins()`

```
$cards = DB::table('cards')
    ->select('cards.id', 'cards.status', 'cards.other_column', 'users.id as user_id', 'users.status as user_status', 'users.other_col')
    ->join('users', 'cards.uid', '=', 'users.id')
    ->orderBy('cards.id','DESC')
    ->get();
```

or

```
$cards = DB::table('cards')
    ->select('cards.*', 'users.id as user_id', 'users.status as user_status', 'users.other_col')
    ->join('users', 'cards.uid', '=', 'users.id')
    ->orderBy('cards.id','DESC')
    ->get();
```

for more info joins see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: i have status in both tables , when i get {{$card->status}} in my view it returns users table status , how i can get cards table status?